# jQuery delay and slow down sliding speed

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, delayed-execution

The following code expands height of the DIV when hover function is performed and how can I change the code such that function has to take place if mouse is placed for 5 seconds. Also how can I slow down the sliding speed?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myhead").hover(

    function () {
        $(this).animate({
            height: '+=250'
        }, '1000');
    }, function () {
        $(this).animate({
            height: '-=250px'
        }, '1000');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this plugin for time based hover http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

this plugin calls the mousein and mouseout function after specific timeout.You can decrease the speed of sliding by

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#myhead").hover(

function () {
    $(this).animate({
        height: '+=50',
    }, {duration:2000});
}, function () {
    $(this).animate({
        height: '-=50px'
    }, {duration:2000});
});
```

});

Comment: what didn't help the speed of the animation or the plugin?

Comment: you can try the edited version of the code or try here at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srgFQ/28/)

Comment: But your answer does not contain delay :(

Comment: you have to use the plugin  i mentioned for  for the delay

Answer (score 1):

There is a jQuery plugin called "hoverintent" which will allow you to write hover functions with a "timeout" property which does what you're describing.

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/hoverIntent

The speed of the animation can be slowed by increasing the number after the animation-- in your current code it's "1000". That's in milliseconds, so 1000 is equal to 1 second.